# Existence of regular representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am reading a book (chapter) on group theory. The chapter I am currently reading is about representations of groups.

The author introduces regular representations and shows that for Abelian groups all irreducible representations are of dimension one. This comes from the fact that the squares of the sums of the dimensions of the representations um up to the group order (= dimension of the representation at hand). 
Furthermore, it is said (in the same paragraph about regular representations) that the dimensions of regular representations divide its order.

Do these statements only work for some groups, i.e. those that have regular representations or every group? And in this regard, does every  group have at least one regular representation?

### Edit

The book I am referring to is "Quantum Mechanics" by Landau and Lifshitz (a physics textbook on quantum mechanics).

A regular representation is defined as:

> [...] a representation of dimension $f=g$, [where $g$ is the group order,] given by the $g$ functions $\hat{G}\psi$, $\psi$ being some general function of the coordinates [$\hat{G}$ correspond to the operators of the group] (so that all the $g$ functions are linearly independent) [...]

Comment: Every group has a unique regular representation, up to equivalence of representations, and this has degree equal to the order of the group.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Please include your definition of "regular representation". Under the standard definition of this term (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_representation)), the question would make no sense, as it uses "regular representations" in the plural, whereas under the standard definition there is exactly one regular representation for a group, which is well-defined so the question of its existence doesn't arise.

Comment: @Shaun please see my edits.

Comment: @joriki I have added the definition.